# SQL : How to get available phone numbers based off of start and end date?

Tags: sql

I have a business that rents out international phone numbers to customers when traveling. 
When a customer makes an order I want to display to the customer the available phone numbers for his booking dates based on his `start_date` and `end_date`.

Since these phone numbers are rented out, I need to select from the table ONLY those numbers that are not rented out yet for dates that would interfere with the current customers dates.

I also don't want to rent out any phone number prior to 7 days after its end date. Meaning, If a customer booked a phone number for 1-1-2020 through 1-20-2020, I don't want this phone number to be booked by another customer before 1-27-2020. I want the phone number to have a 7 day window of being clear.

I have a table with the phone numbers and a table with the orders that is related to the phone numbers table via `phone_number_id`.
The `orders` table has the current customers `start_date` and `end_date` for travel without the phone number id saved yet to it. 
The `orders` table also has the `start_date` and `end_date` for all other customers dates of travel as well as which `phone_number_id` was assigned/booked up for their travel dates.

How would the SQL query look like when trying to select the phone numbers that are available for the current customers dates?

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for phone numbers for which no order overlaps the target rental period. Assuming that the target rental period is defined by parameters `:start_date` and `:end_date`, you could do:

```
select p.*
from phone_numbers p
left join orders o
    on  o.phone_number_id = p.phone_number_id
    and :start_date + interval 7 day <= o.end_date
    and :end_date >= o.start_date + interval 7 day
where o.phone_number_id is null
```

That is: for each phone number, try to find orders whose period overlaps the target rental period (with a 7 day additional clearance), and filter on those for which no overlaping order exist.

Note: the actual syntax to add days to a date may vary depending on your RDBMS.

Comment: Thank you I'm going to try this. How do I ensure the phone number is left with a 7 day window after it's end date before its next start date?

Comment: does this query seem correct to you for my intended logic? select vn.*  from virtualnumbers vn left join orderitemsdetails oid on  oid.vn_id = vn.id and :startdate - interval 7 day <= oid.end_date and :enddate >= oid.start_date where oid.vn_id is null

Comment: @R.P.: yes this could do it as well. Does it produce the results that you expect?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what database you are working with, but here is an example based on Oracle syntax. They key is to add the seven days onto the end date to give the seven day margin.

```
SELECT *
FROM  my_table
WHERE TO_DATE('01/01/2020','MM/DD/YYYY') NOT BETWEEN start_date
                                                 AND end_date + 7
AND   TO_DATE('01/20/2020','MM/DD/YYYY') NOT BETWEEN start_date
                                                 AND end_date + 7
```